# Probability Proof(Finan #5.1.15)

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability, alternative-proof

> Show that $P(A|B)>P(A)$ if and only if $P(A^c |B)<P(A^c)$. We assume
> that $0<P(A)<1$ and $0<P(B)<1$ ( [Finan](https://homepages.uc.edu/%7Ebrycwz/classes/4008/PV2020.pdf) #5.1.5)

Taking the complement of probabilities reverses the sign of the inequality (as shown below):
$$P(X)>P(Y)\Rightarrow-P(X)<P(Y)\Rightarrow1-P(X)<1-P(Y)\Rightarrow P(X^c)<P(Y^c) $$

Hence, take the complement of both sides of $P(A|B)>P(A)$ giving us the desired result
$$P(A^c |B)<P(A^c)$$

Is this correct?

Notes:

1. Finan is a prep guide for Exam Probability of SOA-USA
2. The answer key at the back of the book has a different, lengthier solution.

Comment: Your proof is correct but it is only halfway complete. Note the instructions say show $P(A|B) > P(A)$ *if and only if* $P(A^C|B) < P(A^C)$. Formally speaking, they are asking you to prove $P(A|B) > P(A) \Leftrightarrow P(A^C|B) < P(A^C)$. This means you must first prove $P(A|B) > P(A) \Rightarrow P(A^C|B) < P(A^C)$, which you do, but then you must also prove $P(A^C|B) < P(A^C) \Rightarrow P(A|B) > P(A) $, which you do not

Comment: Agreed. I missed proving the converse.

Comment: I'm posting this response as answer. Let me know if you want help with proving the converse. I doubt it. You have done well so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(A) = 1 - P(A^C)$
$P(A|B) = 1 - P(A^C|B)$

If $P(A|B) > P(A)$ then ...

$1 - P(A^C|B) > 1 - P(A^C)$
$-P(A^C|B) > -P(A^C)$
$P(A^C|B) < P(A^C)$

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as what I did? Please answer the question. Is what I did correct?

Comment: Yes, we did the same thing.

Comment: Your proof is not the same as OP. Furthermore, your poof is only half finished, showing one direction of the implication. You must show the other direciton of the implication due to the "if and only if"

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct but it is only halfway complete. Note the instructions say show $P(A|B)>P(A)$ if and only if $P(AC|B)<P(AC)$. Formally speaking, they are asking you to prove $P(A|B)>P(A)⇔P(AC|B)<P(AC)$. This means you must first prove $P(A|B)>P(A)⇒P(AC|B)<P(AC)$, which you do, but then you must also prove $P(AC|B)<P(AC)⇒P(A|B)>P(A)$, which you do not